# Combining multiple regexs in a sed statement

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I would like to discover the version number of docker-compose.  The format differs per version.

Ex:  Running docker-compose --version

```
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build someId
Docker Compose version v2.12.2
```

I have separate sed statements that grab the version number, but if possible I'd like to combine them.

```
echo `docker-compose --version` | sed -nr 's|^docker-compose version (.*)(,.*)|\1|p'
echo `docker-compose --version` | sed -nr 's|^Docker compose version v(.*)|\1|p'
```

If I or the two regexes together using a pipe, the reference needs to change to either \1 or \3 depending where it's caught.

Is there a better way using sed?

Comment: I'm not convinced there's a good reason to use `sed` here at all. Have you considered bash's built-in regex support?

Comment: No, but I'd be willing to consider it if an example could be made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this single `sed` to grab version number from for both lines shown in question:

```bash
sed -E 's/^[dD]ocker[- ][cC]ompose version +v?([^,]+).*/\1/'

1.29.2
2.12.2
```

**Breakdown:**

- `^`: Start
- `[dD]ocker[- ][cC]ompose version`: Match starting string with mixed cases letters and hyphen/space separator
- `+v?`: Match 1+ spaces followed by an optional `v`
- `([^,]+)`: Match 1+ of any char that is not comma and capture in group #1
- `.*`: Match everything till end
- `\1`: Back-reference to capture group #1

Comment: Thanks so much!  Your answer works great, as does Wiktors! I'm sorry but had to be fair and award the other user the checkmark because he responded 'first'

Comment: Sure, but my answer was posted 25 seconds before the other answer. You can mouse over the `answered` line and check timestamps. `16:42:31` (my answer) vs  `16:42:56`

Comment: Got it. corrected!  I'll let the other user know

Answer (score 3):

Bash has built-in regex support (`[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` stores match group contents in the array `BASH_REMATCH`), so there's no need for `sed` here. The following is more verbose, but faster to run since there's no need to spin up any external executable:

```
dockerComposeVersion=$(docker-compose --version)
dcVersionRegex='[Dd]ocker[ -]compose version v?([^,]+)'

if [[ $dockerComposeVersion =~ $dcVersionRegex ]]; then
  echo "docker-compose version is ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
else
  echo "Unable to get docker-compose version" >&2
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You can merge the two expressions into

```bash
echo `docker-compose --version` | sed -nr 's|^[dD]ocker[ -][cC]ompose version v?([^, ]*).*|\1|p'
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[dD]` - `d` or `D`
- `ocker` - a literal string
- `[ -]` - a space or hyphen
- `[cC]` - `c` or `C`
- `ompose version`  - a fixed string
- `v?` - an optional `v` char
- `([^, ]*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than space and comma
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer works great, as does anubhavas! I'm sorry but had to be fair and award the other user the checkmark because he responded 'first'

Answer (score 2):

In GNU `awk` with your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Using `match` function in GNU `awk` with regex `^([dD]ocker(-c| C)ompose version )v?(([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+),?` to get required values. And if any match is found then its stored into array named `arr` and printing elements 1st and 3rd of arr.

```bash
awk '
match($0,/^([dD]ocker(-c| C)ompose version )v?(([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+),?/,arr){
  print arr[1] arr[3]
}
'  Input_file
```